# application.properties vs hibernate.cfg.xml in spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I've configured hibernate properties in `application.properties` file of my spring boot application.

**application.properties**

```
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.url=<db_url>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy     

# ThymeLeaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache= false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

I am getting error when I am trying to get session as

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("application.properties");
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

**ERROR:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Could not parse configuration: application.properties] with root cause

org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. Nested exception: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I think its expecting `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in the class path as well?

Is there any way I can only use `application.properties` or I have to move all hibernate related properties to `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties` file?

**getSelectedStudents**

```
public List getSelectedStudents(){
    final EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, s.city FROM Student s "
                                    + "where s.city=:city and s.last_name = :lname", Student.class);
    q.setParameter("city", "London");
    q.setParameter("lname", "Rizwan");

    List<Student> students = q.getResultList();

    for (Student s : students) {
        System.out.println("Student "
                + s.getFirstName()
                + " "
                + s.getLastName());
    }

    return students;
}
```

**Error 2:**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.school.service.StudentServiceImplementation.getSelectedStudents(StudentServiceImplementation.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
```

EDIT:
as suggested to use Entity Manager, I've added getSelectedStudents method. I am still getting error at `EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();` 
see Error 2 for details.

Comment: By reading the documentation and not try to use the hibernate way to get a session. Also if you are using Spring Boot why use a `SessionFactory`... Use an `EntityManger` instead. Spring Boot preconfigured the JPA stuff for you, unless you need some specific hibernate features start with JPA instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am using `EntityManager`, but getting error (Error 2) please see update.

Comment: No you aren't... You are using `null`. I strongly suggest a read of the documentation of the framework you are trying to use... Basically the only thing you need to do is to declare a field of type `EntityManager`  in your class, put `@PersistenceContext` on there and be done.

Comment: I did put `@PersistenceContext` at the beginging of my class, but it still warns about it.-----------------Multiple markers at this line
 - Null pointer access: The variable emf can only be null at this location
 - The local variable emf may not have been initialized

Comment: Well of course... Have you actually looked at your code? The first 2 lines of that method, remove them.

Comment: if I remove them, how the Query will be created? `Query q = em.createNativeQuery ("my_sql")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116374/discussion-between-muhammad-and-m-deinum).

Comment: You stated you already have a field of type `Entitymanager` annotated with `@PersistenceContext` that is the entity manager to use. And again I suggest a read of [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) for the frameworks you use (find the section using a `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum, its working. can you add it as an answer and I'll acknowledge that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spring-boot in tandum with spring-autoconfigure, you can simply drop the Hibernate libraries onto your classpath and spring will automatically wire up Hibernate for you.  All you'll need to do is provide some spring jpa configuration settings in your application.properties file and you're done.

If you want to avoid using spring-autoconfigure, then you'll need to add a configuration class that constructs a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, a `JpaTransactionManager` and your `DataSource`.

In either case, to use JPA in your application, you simply need to add an annotated property to your repository or service classes to get an instance to your `EntityManager` as follows:

```
@PersistentContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Spring will make sure to inject this for you and your code simply needs to use it as needed.

Comment: Wider elaboration on this topic I found here: http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/06/spring-boot-data-access-with-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql/

Comment: @Naros I have a question. In your second scenario where we avoided the usage of spring-autoconfigure, can we use hibernate.cfg.xml for the creation of the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: You should be able to create a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in your config class and then load the configuration resource and call `LocalSessionFactoryBean#setConfigLocation` to specify where it should read its configuration, which would be a `Resource` that points to your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.  See https://github.com/himanshuvirmani/Spring-Boot-Security-Example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/himanshu/config/Application.java as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Example. in a configuration class your will need call  @PropertySources and declare a enviroment var .

```
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.sql.DataSource; 
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment; 
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean; 
    import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;

    @Configuration
    @PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") })
    public class DataBaseConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            ..........
            return dataSource;
        }



        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean asfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            asfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
            asfb.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
            asfb.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "your package domain class" });
            return asfb;
        }



        Properties getHibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("schema", environment.getProperty("JNDI.SCHEMA"));
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.DIALECT.PGSQL"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.SQL.SHOW"));
            properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.SQL.FORMAT"));
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.HBM2DDL.AUTO"));
            properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", environment.getProperty("JNDI.SCHEMA"));
            properties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.SQL.COMMENTS"));
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.CHARSET"));
            properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.STATISTICS"));
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.AUTOCOMMIT"));
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.UNICODE"));
            properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.ENABLED.LAZY"));
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", environment.getProperty("HIBERNATE.ENCODING"));
            return properties;

        }


    }
```

And in you "application.properties" file have this.

```
        ################ CONFIGURACION HIBERNATE ################
        HIBERNATE.SEARCH.DEFAULT.PROVIDER=hibernate.search.default.directory_provider
        HIBERNATE.DIALECT.MYSQL=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        HIBERNATE.DIALECT.MSSQL=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        HIBERNATE.DIALECT.PGSQL=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        HIBERNATE.CACHE.SECONDLEVEL=false
        HIBERNATE.CACHE.QUERYCACHE=false
        HIBERNATE.ENABLED.LAZY=hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans
        HIBERNATE.HBM2DDL.AUTO=none   
        HIBERNATE.SQL.COMMENTS=false
        HIBERNATE.SQL.FORMAT=false
        HIBERNATE.STATISTICS=false
        HIBERNATE.AUTOCOMMIT=true
        HIBERNATE.SQL.SHOW=true
        HIBERNATE.ENCODING=utf8
        HIBERNATE.CHARSET=utf8 
        HIBERNATE.UNICODE=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set following in application.yaml

spring:
autoconfigure:
exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration